# How to force a file to download in PHP

Tags: php, html, download

I have list of images and I want a "Download" link along with every image so that user can download the image.

so can someone guide me How to Provide Download link for any file in php?

> **EDIT**

I want a download panel to be displayed on clicking the download link I dont want to navigate to image to be displayed on the browser

Comment: `<a href="path/to/your/file">download</a>`?

Comment: @RaYell he said *in PHP*. So it's actually `echo '<a href="path/to/your/file">download</a>';` :P

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want to force a download, you can use something like the following:

```
<?php
    // Fetch the file info.
    $filePath = '/path/to/file/on/disk.jpg';

    if(file_exists($filePath)) {
        $fileName = basename($filePath);
        $fileSize = filesize($filePath);

        // Output headers.
        header("Cache-Control: private");
        header("Content-Type: application/stream");
        header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);

        // Output file.
        readfile ($filePath);                   
        exit();
    }
    else {
        die('The provided file path is not valid.');
    }
?>
```

If you simply link to this script using a normal link the file will be downloaded.

Incidentally, the code snippet above needs to be executed at the start of a page (before any headers or HTML output had occurred.) **Also take care if you decide to create a function based around this for downloading arbitrary files - you'll need to ensure that you prevent directory traversal ([realpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) is handy), only permit downloads from within a defined area, etc. if you're accepting input from a $_GET or $_POST.**

Comment: Exactly I want this, but how can i connect it with link like "Download" on clicking on which this script should get executed

Comment: +1 Hey dude, it worked but the file downloaded found corrupted,i was not able to open the image..

Comment: @Om then look into the source of the downloaded file for any error messages.

Comment: @OM - just remembered, some browsers get pissy if you don't include a Cache-Control header. (Although that probably isn't the source of your error.) I'll updated the code again.

Comment: @OM What @Pekka is saying is that if you open the downloaded file in a text editor (or simply comment out the header lines in the code) you'll see any PHP errors that occur, hence revealing the cause of the corruption. :-)

Comment: guys i need this stuff to work for image files, document files of all sort... not only for textual readable files

Comment: @OM This code should work for *all* file types - you just need to find out what's causing the corruption.

Comment: @OM Put simply - as a *temporary* measure, comment out the header lines and see if there are any errors being generated. Once these are fixed then un-comment the header lines and all should be well.

Comment: hey geeks i commented three headers lines and I found these errors:: 
{ERRORS}

Warning: filesize() [function.filesize]: stat failed for http://localhost/phptest/nimbuz.jpeg in C:\wamp\www\download.php on line 7

Warning: readfile(http://localhost/phptest/nimbuz.jpeg) [function.readfile]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\wamp\www\download.php on line 15

{/ERRORS}

Comment: @OM You need to: a) Adjust your attitude a bit. b) Provide a valid path to the file on disk. :-)

Comment: @middaparka a) dont take it otherwise, i used to kidd wid Pekka all the time.. I apologize if you felt bad for the fellow SO, 
b) I have provided path as "$filePath = 'C:/wamp/www/phptest/'.$_REQUEST['image'];"

Comment: @OM - If you echo out the full path ($filePath) in the PHP script what is it? (And does that same path work in Windows explorer.) In essence, the errors are both stating that the file can't be found. I've also updated my code a bit.

Comment: @ALL - If on a  windows system, try replacing the forward slash (/) with a backslash (\\)

Comment: @OM - If my previous comment doesn't illustrate the problem, then I'm afraid I don't know what will. :-)

Comment: @webfac - i still get downloaded the curropt image file

Comment: My problem is that this code outputs the file content into browser and do not force a download. What could be the problem in my case?

Comment: @BernhardPointner Are you sure you've not output  *anything* before the calls to `header`? (If you have, the header commands will be ignored, hence you're likely to experience what you describe.) Check your PHP error logs.

Answer (score 4):

In HTML5 `download` attribute of `<a>` tag can be used:

```
echo '<a href="path/to/file" download>Download</a>';
```

> This attribute is only used if the href attribute is set.
>
> There are no restrictions on allowed values, and the browser will
>   automatically detect the correct file extension and add it to the file
>   (.img, .pdf, .txt, .html, etc.).

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp).

Answer (score 2):

The solution is easier that you think ;) Simple use:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
```

And that's all. Facebook for example does the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in .htaccess and specify for different file extensions. It's sometimes easier to do this than hard-coding into the application.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

By the way, you might need to clear browser cache before it works correctly.

Comment: instead of adding the same answer repeated you might consider to flag ,the questions you found as identic, as duplicate.

Comment: They're not duplicate. They are all different questions but have this similar possible solution. The individual answers to each question may be more relevant to people, so flagging it as duplicate may destroy useful information. It's just that the answer I gave may be useful to SOME people searching for these questions. All these questions that I have answered came up in a Google search when I myself was trying to find the answer. It took me a long time to find the solution and I wanted to answer on each one so that anyone searching would also know of this solution.