# PHP Force File Download Code - Error

Tags: php, download

i am using the following code

```
<?php
$rFile = $_GET['sfile'];
$rExt  = $_GET['ext'];
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".urlencode( $_GET['sfile'] ).".".$_GET['ext']);
header('Content-type: Image/jpeg');
readfile( "wallpapers/".$rFILE.$rRes.$rExt );  
?>
```

i pass the variables and the files are being downloaded.. but the images are not being created ..

- i see a image file with image icon with correct name but theres no preview
- the images are not opened in any image viewer (all the images i use are JPEGs)
- all the downloaded images have same size 336 to 337 bytes... so i thought maybe transfer size is limited and so i use [Similar SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476362/how-to-force-a-file-to-download-in-php) but after that only the file size grew to 445bytes to 446bytes nothing more...

WHAT TO DO.. i need to provide direct links for image download...

Comment: The way you accept these variables is potentially dangerous. You should always use `realpath()` to check whether the end result is a child folder of your wallpapers folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bet a beer that the 336 to 337 bytes contain a PHP error message that will tell you what the problem is.

Remove the JPEG content-type header to see the output.

Comment: wooohh... there is this ERROR message ... RESPECT bro.. its is given below

Comment: <br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: rFILE in <b>C:\wamp\www\wallz\download.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  readfile(wallpapers/_4x3jpg) [<a href='function.readfile'>function.readfile</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>C:\wamp\www\wallz\download.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />

Comment: on second though is there a way by which i can setup to force download the file instead of showing in browser.. found the following on the internet but don't know whats it doing

Answer (score 1):

at line 1 you're witing `$rFile`, in line 5 it's `$rFILE` - maybe thats the problem? if not, it's impossible to say without seeing the error-message.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that you are doing some sanitizing of $_GET data or you'll have a lot bigger problems than image data not downloading correctly.  That code is ripe for a directory traversal attack.

Answer (score 0):

okay now i did this

```
$rFile = $_GET['sfile'];
$rExt  = $_GET['ext'];
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".urlencode( $_GET['sfile'] ).".".$_GET['ext']);
header('Content-type: Image/jpeg');
readfile( "wallpapers/".urlencode($rFile).".".$rExt );
```

now the files are being download with correct size.. but i still can't see the preview.. my image veiwers & editors say this

**ACDsee** blank screen

**Windows Page & Fax Viewer** no preview available

**MS Paint** *path* Paint Cannot Read This File This is not a valid bitmap file. Or its format is not supported

Comment: the "Image" ind content-type hast to be lowercase: "image" - but i don't think this is the problem. and: if you have additional infos for your question, please edit the question and provide it there, don't post an answer to your own question if it isn't the solution of the problem (and also that should only be done if nobody else has answered it)