# How do I connect a PHP script for downloading a file to the html link for a song?

Tags: php, download

I have the following table on my website:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Song Name: Far-Sighted</td>
  <td>
   <a href=http://michaelpitluk.com/audio/far_sighted.mp3>Download</a>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

My goal is when people click on "download", their browser will be forced to download the mp3.

I have researched the php script required to do this, but I don't understand how to connect it to the link of the song.

Do I create a new file under my php directory and call it download.php, insert the script, and somehow get it to point to the song?

Here is the php script I'm trying to link to my song:

```
<?php
    // Fetch the file info.
    $filePath = '/path/to/file/on/disk.jpg';

    if(file_exists($filePath)) {
        $fileName = basename($filePath);
        $fileSize = filesize($filePath);

        // Output headers.
        header("Cache-Control: private");
        header("Content-Type: application/stream");
        header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);

        // Output file.
        readfile ($filePath);                   
        exit();
    }
    else {
        die('The provided file path is not valid.');
    }
?>
```

(from: [How to force a file to download in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476362/how-to-force-a-file-to-download-in-php?rq=1))

Comment: umm... you put it wherever you want your download to occur. Since you've provided absolutely not code examples (and no, showing us your site is NOT "code"), we cannot tell you anymore than that.

Comment: @MarcB I updated my question.  Does that help?  What do you mean by "wherever you want your download to occur"? Does that mean next to the html for the link to the song?

Comment: No. you don't put it into the html page that presents the link. you put it into whatever scripts HANDLES the download link. e.g. `http://example.com/download.php?yourfile.txt`

Comment: very basicly i would do this, the link to song would be "download.php?song=song_file" then the download.php would look like your file above but use $_GET['song'] for the file

Comment: Or if your customers have "good enough" browsers you can consider the HTML5 [`download` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download).

Comment: Your script is almost done.  Just set `$filePath` to be whatever is in `$_GET['song']` as Dagon suggested.  Now, be **very careful** that you do not allow folks to download just any file off your disk.  Make sure to keep your music in a specific directory, and check that path to make sure the fully resolved path is the directory you specify.

Comment: @Passerby, That appears to only work in Firefox/Chrome for now.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

Comment: @Brad That's why I emphasize "good enough".

Comment: @Brad I actually got this all working a few days ago! it was the first php script i've ever ran! but, i'm worried about your security caution.  right now, I have a folder for all and only my audio files.  do you mind expanding on your comment a little more?

Comment: @MichaelPitluk, Use `realpath()` on the filename you load, and determine if it is in the path you are allowing.  Otherwise someone might request `file=../../../../etc/passwd` or something.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php