# Force pdf file download upon submit

Tags: php, download

I have a form that submits to a php script which I would like to do the following:

1. capture the user input via POST (done)
2. send me an email with the user's details (done)
3. start downloading a PDF from the same directory as the .php file (test.pdf) - HELP!

EDIT: FYI, I am calling the php via jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: php_url,
    data: $('#popForm').serialize(),
            success: function(){
           window.location.href = 'downloadpdf.php?file=test.pdf';
        }
    })
```

Here is the php code that captures the user input via POST and sends it to me via email.  I just need a section that does #3, above.

```
<?php

$email_PGi = "me@mail.com";
$email_subject = "some email subject";


$firstname = $_POST['firstname']; 
$lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 

$email_message = "The following is a new message received via the website:\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($firstname)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($lastname)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$biz_email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$biz_email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_PGi, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);


?>
```

downloadpdf.php

```
<?php

$file = $_GET['file'];
header('Content-Type: Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . $file);
readfile($filename);
die();

?>
```

Comment: What have you already tried to force the download?

Comment: take a look at this question/answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476362/how-to-force-a-file-to-download-in-php

Comment: I've tried: 

    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename=test.pdf');
    readfile('test.pdf');

...but I'm not sure I'm calling it properly.  Nothing happened..

Comment: @p1xelarchitect Try using an absolute path with `readfile()`

Comment: @RichardA I tried that, no dice :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

It's because the response (with correct headers) is being received by the ajax request, which isn't going to output to the user. You can try one of three things:

1. Don't use ajax for this.
2. Use File API and have the ajax callback handle the file data (major pain).
3. Have the ajax callback set the `window.location` value to a script that only uses the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header so that the browser starts to "redirect" but instead downloads the file as indicated by the header.

Also, possible duplicate of [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Comment: assuming #3 is the simplest option, can you give me a [simple] example?

Comment: `window.location = 'downloadpdf.php?file=test.pdf';`  no href

Answer (score 0):

Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php to send the data along with your headers, not readfile.

Comment: I'm sorry kwolfe, while this may be the answer, none of the examples on the link you shared pertain to what I'm trying to do (download a PDF file).  Can you show me how you would use this in my php script above?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
define('PDF_FILE', 'test.pdf');

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename(PDF_FILE));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize(PDF_FILE));

ob_clean();
flush();

readfile(PDF_FILE);
```

Comment: I tried this exact code and it did not work.  when i hit the submit button, my jquery code (validation) works fine, and I DO receive the email from the php script, but no file download..  

Does it help to know I'm calling the php script via jquery $.ajax()?

Comment: @p1xelarchitect That usually doesn't work I believe. I do think you should've put that in your question though.

Comment: Yes, `jQuery.ajax` couldn't trigger the file-download dialog in the browser. check this: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening a window that forces the download? This is probably not the best nor cleanest solution, but it'll work.

JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: php_url,
    data: $('#popForm').serialize(),
    success: function()
    {
       window.location.href = 'downloadpdf.php?file=test.pdf';
    }
});
```

downloadpdf.php?file=test.pdf

```
$file = $_GET['file'];
header('Content-Type: Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
header('Content-Length: ' . $file);
readfile($filename);
die();
```

I'm not sure if you plan on passing the filename to the callback later on.

Comment: forgive me, I'm new to php... this is probably a silly question, but what is the actual name of the php file in your example?  "downloadpdf.php"  ?

Comment: The name of the file is indeed _downloadpdf.php_ and I'm passing the file name through a `$_GET` variable. Please note that this example assumes that your pdf is in the same folder as downloadpdf.php.

Comment: OK! Closer... I tested it in Safari - no dice - nothing happens.  Tested in IE9, IE10 and FF - it works, but gets caught in the pop up blocker.  Any way around that?

Comment: I edited my answer. Try using `window.location.href = 'downloadpdf.php?file=test.pdf';` instead.

Comment: hmm. yes, that solved the problem in IE - but now it's jamming all the other browsers.  It's calling mydomain.com/downloadpdf.php?file=test.pdf perfectly, but the loading icon just spins forever.  a problem with the php?

Comment: If it works in IE and nowhere else it shouldn't be a PHP thing. Maybe remove the `die();` statement.