# CSV file create and download not working on server with PHP

Tags: php, csv

I want to create CSV file and download it on server.It is working well on local server but it is printing data on live server and there is no option to download the file.
here is the code

```
<?php 
    // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
    header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=utf-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
    ob_start();
    // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
    $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    // output the column headings
    fputcsv($output, array('Id', 'Emp Name', 'Department','Job Number','REG (hours)','OT1 (hours)','OT2','VAC','SIC','HOL','INPUT'));

    $from_date = $_REQUEST['from_date'];
    $to_date = $_REQUEST['to_date'];
    $class = $_REQUEST['class'];
    $job = $_REQUEST['job'];
    $str = '';
    if ($class!='') {
        $str.= " AND class='".$class."'";
    }
    if ($job!='') {
        $str.= " AND  job_number ='".$job."'";
    }
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE punch_in_time BETWEEN '".$from_date."' AND '".$to_date."' $str";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$Link);

    $weekfrom = array();
    $weekto = array();
    $start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from_date));
    $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($to_date));
    $end_date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($to_date . '+ 6 days'));

    for ($date = $start_date; $date <= $end_date1; $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' + 14 days'))) {

      $week = date('W', strtotime($date));
      $year = date('Y', strtotime($date));
      $from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}+1 - 1 day")); //Returns the date of monday in week
      if ($from < $start_date)
        $from = $start_date;
      $to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-6 + 1 week"));   //Returns the date of sunday in week
      if ($to > $end_date) {
        $to = $end_date;
      }
      if ($from < $to) {
        array_push($weekfrom, $from);
        array_push($weekto, $to);
      }
    }
    $n = count($weekfrom);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
      $week_start[$i] = $weekfrom[$i];
      $week_end[$i] = $weekto[$i] . "\n";
    }

    $num = mysql_num_rows($res);
    $k=1;
    if ($num > 0) {
    // loop over the rows, outputting them
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
         $classname = 'testClass';
         $empname =    '11233';

          $total_punched_hours = 10;

             $arr = array($k,$empname,$classname,$row['job_number'],$total_punched_hours,'15','1','5','4','55','44');
             $result = fputcsv($output, $arr); 
             $k++;
        }

    }
    fclose($output);

?>
```

Comment: try saving it, if it is giving the file name as <filename>.csv then it is fine.

Comment: I want to force download

Comment: try with this header. 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476362/how-to-force-a-file-to-download-in-php

Answer (score 3):

using ob_start() at the top of the page did solve this issue.Hope it will helpful for other users as well.