# How to create a link to download a php file?

Tags: php, html

I have a website, and I want to be able to put a link that enables the user to download a php file, I don't want it to run or for the user to navigate to the url, but be able to download the original file, is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Follow this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476362/how-to-force-a-file-to-download-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476362/how-to-force-a-file-to-download-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Biswajit, that link got me what I needed (I saw the original "duplicate" but I wasn't working for me)

```
<?php
    // Fetch the file info.
    $filePath = '/path/to/file/on/disk.jpg';

    if(file_exists($filePath)) {
        $fileName = basename($filePath);
        $fileSize = filesize($filePath);

        // Output headers.
        header("Cache-Control: private");
        header("Content-Type: application/stream");
        header("Content-Length: ".$fileSize);
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$fileName);

        // Output file.
        readfile ($filePath);                   
        exit();
    }
    else {
        die('The provided file path is not valid.');
    }
?>
```

Comment: I know this is old, but will this allow me to just list some file names on a page as links and when the user clicks any of the links it will call the above script forcing the download - which would also essentially hide the true path of the file, even if it was a true web URL path?  If this works this way then I can lockdown/hide the URLs from browsers but still make the files downloadable only by users who should have access to them.