# Export a mysql database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, download, export

I am facing an issue when I am exporting, then it displays as texts in browser instead of download file. I want to know what is wrong in my code for export database (sql file) with core PHP. Below is my code:

```
$host      = DB_SERVER;
$user      = DB_USERNAME;
$pass      = DB_PASSWORD;
$name      = DB_DATABASE;
$tables=false;
$backup_name=false;
set_time_limit(3000);
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$name);
$mysqli->select_db($name); $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$queryTables = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES');

while($row = $queryTables->fetch_row()) {
   $target_tables[] = $row[0];
}

if($tables !== false) {
  $target_tables = array_intersect( $target_tables, $tables);
} 
$content = "SET SQL_MODE = \"NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO\";\r\nSET time_zone = \"+00:00\";\r\n\r\n\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;\r\n/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;\r\n/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;\r\n--\r\n-- Database: `".$name."`\r\n--\r\n\r\n\r\n";

 foreach($target_tables as $table){
        if (empty($table)){ continue; } 
        $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM `'.$table.'`');     
        $fields_amount=$result->field_count;
        $rows_num=$mysqli->affected_rows;
        $res = $mysqli->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table);
        $TableMLine=$res->fetch_row(); 
        $content .= "\n\n".$TableMLine[1].";\n\n"; $TableMLine[1]=str_ireplace('CREATE TABLE `','CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `',$TableMLine[1]);

        for ($i = 0, $st_counter = 0; $i < $fields_amount;   $i++, $st_counter=0) {
               while($row = $result->fetch_row())   { //when started (and every after 100 command cycle):
                if ($st_counter%100 == 0 || $st_counter == 0 )  {$content .= "\nINSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES";}
                    $content .= "\n(";    for($j=0; $j<$fields_amount; $j++){ $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n", addslashes($row[$j]) );
                    if (isset($row[$j])){$content .= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ;}
                    else{$content .= '""';}
                    if ($j<($fields_amount-1)){$content.= ',';}
                }
        $content .=")";
        //every after 100 command cycle [or at last line] ....p.s. but should be inserted 1 cycle eariler
        if ( (($st_counter+1)%100==0 && $st_counter!=0) || $st_counter+1==$rows_num) {$content .= ";";} else {$content .= ",";} $st_counter=$st_counter+1;
            }
        } $content .="\n\n\n";
    }
    $content .= "\r\n\r\n/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;\r\n/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;\r\n/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;";
    $backup_name = $backup_name ? $backup_name : $name.'___('.date('H-i-s').'_'.date('d-m-Y').').sql';
    ob_get_clean();
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header('Content-Length: '. (function_exists('mb_strlen') ? mb_strlen($content, '8bit'): strlen($content)) );
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$backup_name."\""); 

    echo $content; exit;
```

Please anyone tell me what I am missing here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's code? That looks like a monstrosity

Comment: You need to write the content to disk first file_put_contents and use readFile after the `header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$backup_name."\""); `  check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476362/how-to-force-a-file-to-download-in-php

Comment: I had tried readfile also but it is doing same displays texts and didn't download the file.