# PHP imagejpeg - Trigger Download

Tags: php, imagejpeg

I am using PHP imagejpeg to create a simple image like this..

```
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Output the image
imagejpeg($im);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
```

This is working, but i would like it to automatically trigger a download inside the browser instead of display the image.

How can I do this, do I need to set a header?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a file to download in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476362/how-to-force-a-file-to-download-in-php)

Comment: Has any of available answers answered your question? :)

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is set an extra header:

```
// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);

// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file-name.jpg'); // This will tell the browser to download it

// Output the image
imagejpeg($im);

// Free up memory
imagedestroy($im);
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) is the documentation

Comment: Does nothing for me

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested it with your code and it's working fine, I updated with the code I tested with

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need at least 3 headers:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); // Content type
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file-name.jpg"); // Content deposition
header("Content-Length: $fileSize"); // YOUR FILE SIZE
```

otherwise, the download will not work in firefox.