# Export mysql db using php script only works on local not on live server

Tags: php

i'm trying export db to .sql file using php script, And it works well in local as when i click on link the file downloads to default download path, but when i try it on live server it shows the text on the web page and do not download. I have tried removing all the spaces after php to thinking it might be a problem, But The problem remains

below is the code i used

```
    function EXPORT_TABLES($host,$username,$password,$db,$tables=false, $backup_name=false ){
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$db);
    $mysqli->select_db($db);
    $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $queryTables = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES');
    while($row = $queryTables->fetch_row()){
        $target_tables[] = $row[0];
    }
    if($tables !== false){
        $target_tables = array_intersect( $target_tables, $tables);
    }
    foreach($target_tables as $table){
        $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $fields_amount=$result->field_count;
        $rows_num=$mysqli->affected_rows;
        $res = $mysqli->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table);
        $TableMLine=$res->fetch_row();
        $content = (!isset($content) ?  '' : $content) . "\n\n".$TableMLine[1].";\n\n";
        for ($i = 0, $st_counter = 0; $i < $fields_amount;   $i++, $st_counter=0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_row()){//when started (and every after 100 command cycle):
                if ($st_counter%100 == 0 || $st_counter == 0 ){
                        $content .= "\nINSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES";
                    }
                $content .= "\n(";
                for($j=0; $j<$fields_amount; $j++){
                    $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n", addslashes($row[$j]) );
                    if (isset($row[$j])){
                        $content .= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ;
                    }else {
                        $content .= '""';
                    }
                    if ($j<($fields_amount-1))
                    {
                        $content.= ',';
                    }
                }
                $content .=")";
                //every after 100 command cycle [or at last line] ....p.s. but should be inserted 1 cycle eariler
                if ( (($st_counter+1)%100==0 && $st_counter!=0) || $st_counter+1==$rows_num){
                    $content .= ";";
                }else{
                    $content .= ",";
                }
                $st_counter=$st_counter+1;
            }
        } $content .="\n\n\n";
    }
    $backup_name = $backup_name ? $backup_name : $db."___(".date('H-i-s')."_".date('d-m-Y').").sql";
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$backup_name."\"");
    echo $content;
    /*$handle = fopen($backup_name,'w+');
    fwrite($handle,$content);
    fclose($handle);
    echo 'done';*/
    exit;
}
```

using fwrite i can get the file but it saves in root directry.

Not duplicate: this is not a image, we are writing some text then saving it as .SQL file, either by forcing it or not it is still showing the text rather downloading

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a file to download in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476362/how-to-force-a-file-to-download-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a folder for fwrite:

```
$folder = "temp";
if(!file_exists($folder)){          //Check if dir already exists
    mkdir($folder, 0777, true)      //Create one if it doesn't and set the file permission, adjust to your taste.
}

$handle = fopen($folder.'/'.$backup_name,'w+');
fwrite($handle,$content);
fclose($handle);
echo 'done';
```

Comment: how do i save it to mobile memory? is it possible using php?